# Why function prologue is not showing in function disassembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, callstack

I'm trying to understand how a function call works in assembly language. My understanding is, after calling a function, `the callee` function first uses a `function prologue` to create a new stack frame for itself.

Function prologue:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

However, I have the following example code,

```
void printNumber(int nbr){
   printf("%d\n", nbr);
}

void myFunction(void (*f)(int)){
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      (*f)(i);
   }
}

int main(void){
   myFunction(printNumber);
   return (0); 
}
```

Disassembly of all the function is :

```
>>> disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x000000000040057b <+0>:    sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x000000000040057f <+4>:    mov    $0x400526,%edi
0x0000000000400584 <+9>:    callq  0x400549 <myFunction>
0x0000000000400589 <+14>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040058e <+19>:   add    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000400592 <+23>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.

>>> disass myFunction
Dump of assembler code for function myFunction:
0x0000000000400549 <+0>:    sub    $0x28,%rsp
0x000000000040054d <+4>:    mov    %rdi,0x8(%rsp)
0x0000000000400552 <+9>:    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%rsp)
0x000000000040055a <+17>:   jmp    0x40056e <myFunction+37>
0x000000000040055c <+19>:   mov    0x1c(%rsp),%edx
0x0000000000400560 <+23>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
0x0000000000400565 <+28>:   mov    %edx,%edi
0x0000000000400567 <+30>:   callq  *%rax
0x0000000000400569 <+32>:   addl   $0x1,0x1c(%rsp)
0x000000000040056e <+37>:   cmpl   $0x4,0x1c(%rsp)
0x0000000000400573 <+42>:   jle    0x40055c <myFunction+19>
0x0000000000400575 <+44>:   nop
0x0000000000400576 <+45>:   add    $0x28,%rsp
0x000000000040057a <+49>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.

>>> disass printNumber
Dump of assembler code for function printNumber:
0x0000000000400526 <+0>:    sub    $0x18,%rsp
0x000000000040052a <+4>:    mov    %edi,0xc(%rsp)
0x000000000040052e <+8>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
0x0000000000400532 <+12>:   mov    %eax,%esi
0x0000000000400534 <+14>:   mov    $0x400624,%edi
0x0000000000400539 <+19>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040053e <+24>:   callq  0x400400 <printf@plt>
0x0000000000400543 <+29>:   nop
0x0000000000400544 <+30>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
0x0000000000400548 <+34>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

None of the functions disassemblies shows function prologue. This brings to my questions,

1. Why `function prologue` is not showing in function disassembly?
2. In all the function disassemblies, my understanding is `sub` instruction is allocating some space in the stack for local variables and sub-routine.

   - In main function, It only has one subroutine `myFunction(printNumber);`. Therefore, I guess `sub    $0x8,%rsp` is being used to allocate 8-byte stack memory for sub-routine call.
   - But, in other two functions, why allocating more stack memory? For example, function `printNumber` took one `int` type argument. Then what allocating `24-bytes` in the stack?

Update:
I have compiled with following,

```
gcc -O0 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -o function_as_paprameter function_as_paprameter.c
```

Comment: The prologue can be omitted as an optimization.  This is the `-fomit-frame-pointer` option which is often enabled by default.  Local variables can be accessed relative to `%rsp` instead of `%rbp` as you see, which makes it unnecessary to set up the stack frame with `%rbp` at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge. Thank you. Now I can see the prologue.

Comment: The only prologue needed is the `sub    $0x28,%rsp` to reserve space for locals.  The instructions involving RBP you were expecting to see *are part* of the prologue if they're present at all, but are optional in modern calling conventions / ABIs.  It's not correct to say that `push   %rbp` / `mov    %rsp,%rbp` *is* the function prologue.

Comment: Did you compile this with `-O1` or `-Og`?  The loop in `myFunction` is strangely keeping `i` in memory, and reloading the function pointer arg as well.  Include your compile options as part of a [mcve].  (And if you want, link to the code on https://godbolt.org/ with those options.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I use `-O0 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for compilation.

Comment: On what system, with what GCC version?  (`gcc -v`)  A normal config of GCC uses `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` at `-O0`, and would reference stack locals relative to RBP (after setting up RBP as a frame pointer at the top of each function like you were expecting).  But yeah that does otherwise look like `-O0` code, spilling incoming register args to memory and never keeping a var in regs across C statements.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm running 64-bit Linux 16.04 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-200-generic. removing  `-fomit-frame-pointer` from the compiling options actually let me see the desire prologue.

Comment: Oh, so you were using `-fomit-frame-pointer` explicitly, along with `-O0`, but you didn't include that in your comment (only in your question edit which I didn't examine closely).  Ok, that totally explains everything, with that option doing exactly what it says on the tin.